# How to read files in directory in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, readfile

In my node.js app, I load modules from a folder, and put them in an array. Right now I do it manually like this

```
var sitesList = [
    require('./js/sites/A.js'),
    require('./js/sites/B.js'),
    require('./js/sites/C.js')
];
```

but over time, I don't want to add the file name to this list everytime I add a new module. How can I just loop through all js files in the sites folder and auto add them in an array?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_callback

Comment: can u show how to use it in an example code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var normalizedPath = require("path").join(__dirname, "js/sites");
var sitesList = [];
var fs = require("fs");
fs.readdirSync(normalizedPath).forEach(function(file) {
    sitesList.push(require("./js/sites/" + file));
});
```

you can also look into this module:

https://github.com/felixge/node-require-all